# Reading Last *n* lines from GZIPInputStream

Tags: java, gzip, gzipinputstream

I am reading a huge txt file inside zip.

```
GZIPInputStream fstream = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipfile));
BufferedReader breader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
```

I need to read **last** n lines, of the file.

Is it possible to do that without readline until eof?

Comment: it is not possible to read stream/dictionary compressed "file", unless there is something like Z_FULL_FLUSH (and dumping the dictionary)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Is it possible to do that without readline until eof?*

No and well due to the following two reasons:

1. You cannot read a stream backwards.
2. You cannot un(g)zip backwards.

Just read the entire stream wherein you ignore the lines which you aren't interested in.

Comment: technically it's possible to read past Z_FULL_FLUSH mark (provided anyone would bother to place)